# log4j2 logs from unknown source

Tags: java, xml, log4j2

I am attempting to learn logging (log4j2)

This is my log4j2 config XML file

`log4j2_config_6_appenders.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console1_sout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[Console1_sout] %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="Console2_serr" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[Console2_serr] %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="logger1_sout" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console1_sout"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="logger2_serr" level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console2_serr"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is my test

```
    @Test
    public void test_consoleAppender() {
        setLog4j2ConfigFile("log4j2_config_6_appenders.xml");
        final Logger logger1_sout = LogManager.getLogger("logger1_sout");
        final Logger logger2_serr = LogManager.getLogger("logger2_serr");
        final Logger[] loggers = new Logger[]{logger1_sout, logger2_serr};
        for (Logger logger : loggers) {
            logger.trace("This is a trace message");
            logger.debug("This is a debug message");
            logger.info("This is an info message");
            logger.warn("This is a warning message");
            logger.error("This is an error message");
            logger.fatal("This is a fatal message");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

This is the output

```
[Console1_sout] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] TRACE logger1_sout - This is a trace message
16:12:49.545 [main] TRACE logger1_sout - This is a trace message
[Console1_sout] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] DEBUG logger1_sout - This is a debug message
16:12:49.547 [main] DEBUG logger1_sout - This is a debug message
[Console1_sout] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] INFO  logger1_sout - This is an info message
16:12:49.547 [main] INFO  logger1_sout - This is an info message
[Console1_sout] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] WARN  logger1_sout - This is a warning message
16:12:49.547 [main] WARN  logger1_sout - This is a warning message
[Console1_sout] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] ERROR logger1_sout - This is an error message
16:12:49.547 [main] ERROR logger1_sout - This is an error message
[Console1_sout] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] FATAL logger1_sout - This is a fatal message
16:12:49.547 [main] FATAL logger1_sout - This is a fatal message

16:12:49.548 [main] TRACE logger2_serr - This is a trace message
16:12:49.548 [main] DEBUG logger2_serr - This is a debug message
16:12:49.548 [main] INFO  logger2_serr - This is an info message
16:12:49.548 [main] WARN  logger2_serr - This is a warning message
16:12:49.548 [main] ERROR logger2_serr - This is an error message
16:12:49.548 [main] FATAL logger2_serr - This is a fatal message


[Console2_serr] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] TRACE logger2_serr - This is a trace message
[Console2_serr] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] DEBUG logger2_serr - This is a debug message
[Console2_serr] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] INFO  logger2_serr - This is an info message
[Console2_serr] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] WARN  logger2_serr - This is a warning message
[Console2_serr] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] ERROR logger2_serr - This is an error message
[Console2_serr] 2018-Jul-06 16:12:49 PM [main] FATAL logger2_serr - This is a fatal message
```

**Question**

Why are there logs that do not contain neither "[Console2_serr]" nor "[Console1_sout]"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because of missing additivity and the root logger configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console1_sout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[Console1_sout] %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="Console2_serr" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[Console2_serr] %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="logger1_sout" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console1_sout"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="logger2_serr" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console2_serr"/>
        </Logger>
         <Root level="trace" additivity="false">
              <AppenderRef ref="Console1_sout"/>
              <AppenderRef ref="Console2_serr"/>
         </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Try something like this.
The additivity let you consume log row at first time and prevent interception by another logger.

Comment: I tried adding the rootLogger before, it didn't prevent the issue. Now i added the "additivity" and it works.
Can you recommend a decent detailed tutorial for log4j2?

Comment: I can recommend the official tutorial, it is a little bit morbose but detailed. You can read it  [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html). Read also the [additivity](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity) section

Comment: Thank you, i am already using it. Every other tutorial have some issues.